# Filter data with LINQ from List or DataSet in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to Linq, I have a data in `DataSet` and also in `List` similar to this; I need to enter count of rows against each Name with respect to month and year and amount should not be 0 or null, also retuned data should be ascending order.

```
Name    Month   Year    Amount
A       3       1999    10
A       3       1999    10
A       1       1998    10
A       5       2002    10
A       9       2009         // amount is empty
B       1       1999    10
B       1       1999    0   // amount is zero
B       6       2002    10
B       9       2009    10
B       2       1998    10
B       1       1998    10
B       1       1998    10
```

How can I convert my data like this;

```
Name    01/1998  02/1998    03/1999          05/2002    06/2002  09/2009
A       1        0          2                1          0        0 // amount was null
B       2        1          1 /*one was 0*/  0          1        1
```

I have tried like below query but I guess due to my less knowledge to LINQ, i am making mistake somewhere;

```
var query = dataList
    .GroupBy(a => a.Name)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Name = g.Key
        Jan98 = g.Where(c => c.Day == g.Day).Count()
    });
```

I have also searched, but none of the found was helping for this type of filtration. I am ale to filter this in Excel pivot table. I want to do this in c#. Any other way except LINQ will also be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked here? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167304/is-it-possible-to-pivot-data-using-linq)

Comment: checked this and even followed this, but unable tou row count @ShayD

Comment: Would this give something? `Jan98 = g.Where(c => c.Month == 1 && c.Year == 1998).Count(x => x.Amount.HasValue ? x.Amount.Value : 0)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested GroupBy LINQ Using Fluent Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001256/nested-groupby-linq-using-fluent-syntax)

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer making this more verbose and less LINQy just to avoid big queries, but there is still a way to do what you want with LINQ:

```
var items = data.Where(x => x.Amount != null && x.Amount != 0)
                .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, 
                              x => x.GroupBy(t => (t.Month, t.Year))
                                    .ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Count()));
```

We can iterate over this thing like this:

```
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key}\t");
            foreach (var v in items[item.Key].OrderBy(x => x.Key.Year).ThenBy(x => x.Key.Month))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{v.Key}\t{v.Value}");   
            }
        }
```

The output provided your sample data would be:

```
A
(1, 1998)       1
(3, 1999)       2
(5, 2002)       1
B
(1, 1998)       2
(2, 1998)       1
(1, 1999)       1
(6, 2002)       1
(9, 2009)       1
```

If you are trying to get one element you would do something like:

```
int count = items["A"][(1, 1998)]; // count == 1
```

Comment: You can place the `Where` condition first to save some useless `DateTime` creation.

Comment: In fact, the `OrderBy` is useless since everything goes to a dictionary that doesn't preserve order.

Comment: @Orace true. I thought that the undetermenstic order only takes place after the initialization and not in ctor, but after taking a look at the `Dictionary` sources it appears that's not the case. Thanks, changed my usage example.

Answer (score 1):

Here a `IQueryable`version:

```
var query = dataList
    .Where(r => r.Amount.HasValue && r.Amount.Value != 0) // discard 0 and null
    .GroupBy(r => r.Name).OrderBy(r => r.Key) // group and sort by name
    // now project each name-group (ng) to a 2-tuple:
    //   1. The group key
    //   2. The elements grouped and order by date.
    .Select(ng => (ng.Key, ng.GroupBy(r => (r.Year, r.Mounth)).OrderBy(dg => dg.Key.Year).ThenBy(gd => gd.Key.Mounth)));

foreach (var (name, dateGroup) in query)
{
    foreach (var g in dateGroup)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"For name {name} in {g.Key.Mounth}/{g.Key.Year}. Count is {g.Count()}. Amount sum is {g.Sum(r => r.Amount)}");
    }
}
```